# Django unique combination of foreign keys

Tags: python, django

I have 4 django models:

```
class KeyOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class KeyTwo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class KeyThree(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True)

class KeyList(models.Model):
    key_one = models.ForeignKey(KeyOne)
    key_two = models.ForeignKey(KeyTwo)
    key_three = models.ForeignKey(KeyThree)
    list = models.CharField()
```

Basically, `KeyList` is a list of keywords associated with different combinations of `KeyOne`, `KeyTwo` and `KeyThree`. How do I make sure that, in the Django Admin, only unique combos can be entered?

Comment: Try with [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#unique-together) in `class Meta:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set in the Meta class in the KeyList:

```
class KeyList(models.Model):
    key_one = models.ForeignKey(KeyOne)
    key_two = models.ForeignKey(KeyTwo)
    key_three = models.ForeignKey(KeyThree)
    list = models.CharField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("key_one", "key_two", "key_three"),)
```

Comment: This is wrong. Unique together is an old and almost deprecated feature in old versions of Django. It interprets to raw SQL unique constraint on tables and in SQL, it means it cannot be used in Foreign key relationships, blob and text fields where their sizes cannot be known beforehand. Unique Constraints should be used instead just as the docs recommend. This is a powerful and very flexible feature.

Answer (score 11):

**Django > 2.2**

[Django Documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

*Use UniqueConstraint with the constraints option instead.
UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together. unique_together may be deprecated in the future.*

So in your case:

```py
class KeyList(models.Model):
    key_one = models.ForeignKey(KeyOne)
    key_two = models.ForeignKey(KeyTwo)
    key_three = models.ForeignKey(KeyThree)
    list = models.CharField()
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["key_one", "key_two", "key_three"], name="all_keys_unique_together")
]
```